# Assuring an unsigned long int?

Tags: variables

Basic question: How far do I have to go to assure that integer math is done correctly? For example, this is probably overdone:

```
unsigned long burnTime = 0UL;
unsigned long curBurnTime = 0UL;
// Do some stuff that sets the above variables to millis() at various times
// Later on...
unsigned long adjustedBurnTime = (unsigned long) ((burnTime + curBurnTime) / 1000UL);
```

Would the math be done correctly if I went to a more minimal last statement (since all the elements of the equation are unsigned longs)? Like this:

```
unsigned long adjustedBurnTime = ((burnTime + curBurnTime) / 1000UL);
```

Or even:

```
unsigned long adjustedBurnTime = ((burnTime + curBurnTime) / 1000);
```

Comment: Only one way to really find out! Compile them both and disassemble them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams either that or read through the GCC compiler code. :) Printing output to serial is, of course, the easiest!

Comment: If argument of math operation is unsigned long then it should be calculated in long precision and potentially shortened when assigned. I.e.second case should be ok. But double checking in assembly is the best choice how to save time when provides strange results.

Comment: This issue is very relavent to time; check out http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TimingRollover it outlines the same issue. Where I would agree with TMA, in that since all are casted the same, it is not needed. However, I always play it safe. In case the casting was changed.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I'm not savvy enough to check the assembly code so I'll try the serial output route. @mpflaga, I agree better safe than sorry. I was just hoping to be (safely) a little less redundant in my code but why take a chance, I suppose. Since I'm tracking runtimes it _will_ be an issue.

Comment: I compiled all three of the examples above and the result was three identical hex files. Unless I'm missing something it seems I've answered my question. ...Am I missing something?

Comment: No, your're not; the hex file exactly represents your code (plus some loading instructions). If two hex files are identical, and presented to the same loader, the results (the memory loads) have to be identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any good C manual will tell you the result type for each basic math operation on given types. But briefly, the basic math operators return a result as wide as the widest operand, with the narrower operand being widened to match the wider one, if they differ. The same with assignment: assigning a result of a given type to a variable of the same type will not involve any conversion.

tl;dr: No, you're not missing anything. You don't need any casts in your example.

PS: One thing you do need to be aware of is whether any of your intermediate results will overflow the arithmetic type you're using. For example, the final result may be not exceed an unsigned long but the expressions `(burnTime + curBurnTime)` must also not exceed it. This is a greater concern with smaller data-types, of course.

PPS: Good on you for tackling fixed point arithmetic rather than just reaching for the floating-point library!

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer because it explains not just whether but why. My uninformed guess would have been the opposite. Also very appreciative of the warning on intermediate results; it would have been just a matter of time until that bit me.